# how to get group having no child in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am using Custom `ExpandableListview` for first time. I have custom expandable listview which contains 10 groups in which some groups have child and some groups don't have child.

I want child when the child item is clicked. (in case of groups having child)

I want group when the group item is clicked. (in case of groups don't have child)

I am getting child by using `OnChildClickListener`(first case) , but I didn't getting group. (second case)

Is there any way to get both at a time. If group have child then return clicked child otherwise return clicked group.

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set `OnChildClickListener` to list

Next set `OnGroupExpandListener` to list

```
exList.setOnChildClickListener(this);
exList.setOnGroupExpandListener(this);

@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    Group gr = ds_list.get(groupPosition);
    //here you can get child from group
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onGroupExpand(int i) {
    if(group don't have child) {
        //get group by using group position(i)
    }
}
```

You can add `OnGroupCollapseListener` also

Don't use `OnChildClickListener` and `OnGroupExpandListener` together because group items are not expandable behaves like a normal `ListView`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to get the index of parent view, and check whether the parent in that position contains a child or not.

```
expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
        //here you can check whether your parent contains a child or not by getting the parent position.
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by "not working"? What happens when you tries to add that code?

Comment: when i click on groups its not going to OnItemClick() method

Comment: OnGroupListener only giving the groups.childs are not getting.

Comment: it is giving you the position of parent in that group. You can check manually whether that group contains a child or not.

Comment: groups is just clickable like normal listview but groups is not expanding. its not showing the childs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101284/discussion-between-hari-krishnan-and-yugandhar).